# Set NS server for one level domain name

Tags: domain-name-system

If there is a record in ns1.example.com:

```
xxx   NS      ns2.example.com.
```

is it possible to make yyy.xxx domain to be resolve in ns1.example.com ?
With the current configuration *.xxx domain resolution go to ns2.example.com, but what I need is just xxx domain to be resolved in ns2.example.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible as far as I know. When you delegate control of a subdomain (in your case `xxx.example.com`) you delegate the control of the entire DNS tree starting at that subdomain, thus also `yyy.xxx.example.com`.